# How to remove the first word from a large string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to remove the first word from a large string in SQL Server.

Input string:

```
931078027 BP 16:20:0:13 25 BAG 'B' CLASS
```

Desired output:

```
BP 16:20:0:13 25 BAG 'B' CLASS
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use a substring operation, e.g.

```sql
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '931078027 BP 16:20:0:13 25 BAG ''B'' CLASS' AS val
)

SELECT val,
       SUBSTRING(val,
                 CHARINDEX(' ', val) + 1,
                 LEN(val) - CHARINDEX(' ', val)) AS val_out
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

I believe most easy way is to use **RIGHT** method to get it.

```
SELECT RIGHT(ColumnName, CHARINDEX(' ', ColumnName) - 1) FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `STUFF()` function.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(MAX) = '931078027 BP 16:20:0:13 25 BAG ''B'' CLASS';

SELECT @input AS input
    , STUFF(@input, 1, CHARINDEX(SPACE(1), @input), '') AS [output];
```

**Output**

```
+------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|                  input                   |             output             |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| 931078027 BP 16:20:0:13 25 BAG 'B' CLASS | BP 16:20:0:13 25 BAG 'B' CLASS |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT SUBSTRING(columnname, charindex(' ', columnname),LEN(columnname)-charindex(' ', columnname)+1) from tablename